# Location Services Error

Tags: ios, core-location

My app uses Core Location. The only place I access the Location manager after initialization is in the delegate where I grab the current location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray*)locations
{
}
```

When the app starts up, the delegate gets called through

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

with kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized. All fine.

Then this gets called:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error) ;
    return ;
}
```

giving the error:

```
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)
```

After that, everything behaves as I would expect. Locations come in with no problem. This error does not seem to indicate a real problem.

Does anyone know if 1) there is some way to avoid this error at startup and 2) is there some way for me to differentiate between this apparently meaningless error and one that I should pay attention to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error come only when you are in the simulator, right :) ?

If you try the app **on your iPhone, it will not show the error**.

If you want to solve the error **in the simulator**, each time that you launch the app, **choose a location in the menu of the simulator app ~> Debug ~> Location**.

Comment: I get this error on a device specifically 5th gen. iPod, so it's not exclusive to the simulator.